# Capture SQL procedure execution time and other metrics

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqlperformance

I need to know a way of capturing performance metrics of the SQLs that are invoked by my application. For example, there is a procedure Proc_test which is executed on certain action from the application. This procedure may be executed N number of times. I need to capture the execution time, cpu time and all the metrics which are helpful to analyze performance. These metrics needs to be collected on every execution. I have tried the AWR report, but it only provides details on the top SQLs.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks & Peace

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [v$sql](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75.htm#REFRN30246) view, which provides columns `executions`, `elapsed_time`, and `cpu_time`